# How to Ignore the list if values are empty in c#

Tags: c#, list

My Class like below

```
public class SubscriptionDetailModel
{

    public SubscriptionDetailModel()
    { 
        cap = new List<Subscriptioninfo>();
        filter = new List<Subscriptioninfofilter>();
        schedule = new List<SubscriptioninfoSchedule>();
    }
    public List<Subscriptioninfo> cap { get; set; }
    public List<Subscriptioninfofilter> filter { get; set; }
    public List<SubscriptioninfoSchedule> schedule { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Nullable<int> SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriptioninfo
{
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AccountID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubscriptionCapID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LeadCapTypeId { get; set; }
    public string LeadCapType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriptioninfofilter
{
    public Nullable<int> SubscriptionFilterID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubscriptionFilterTypeID { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionFilterTypeInputValue { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionFilterTypeName { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionFilterTypeOperator { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriptioninfoSchedule
{
    public int SubscriptionScheduleId { get; set; }
    public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int TimeZoneCode { get; set; }
}
```

my output like below for schedule

```
"response":"200","message":"Success","data":[{"cap":[],"filter":[],"schedule":[{"SubscriptionScheduleId":5,"DayOfWeek":"Thursday","StartTime":"2017-01-12T12:00:00","EndTime":"2017-01-12T20:30:00","CreatedDate":"2017-01-11T00:00:00","ModifiedDate":null,"TimeZoneCode":8}],"Name":null}]}
```

Now my question is how to remove  **"cap":[ ],"filter":[ ]** from response.
we are able to IgnoreDataMember if `Public Nullable<int> SubscriptionID {get;set;}`

but i dont know how to ignore the list like above.

My result should be like below

```
"response":"200","message":"Success","data":[{"schedule":[{"SubscriptionScheduleId":5,"DayOfWeek":"Thursday","StartTime":"2017-01-12T12:00:00","EndTime":"2017-01-12T20:30:00","CreatedDate":"2017-01-11T00:00:00","ModifiedDate":null,"TimeZoneCode":8}],"Name":null}]}
```

Comment: are you using `Json.NET`?

Comment: no i am not using Json.NET

Answer (score 2):

An empty list is something else than a property with the null value. The latter will be omitted, the first not. (That is why setting JSON.NET's `NullValueHandling` is useless in this scenario.)

The 'solution' is to set the empty lists to `null`. Then the JSON serializer will omit them. Another solution when you use JSON.NET is to write a custom serializer which excludes empty lists from serializing. Both not ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom json serializer, then it is hard to suggest another solution, different than @PatrickHofman suggested, anyway the simple answer is to set your properties to `null` before serializing:

```
SubscriptionDetailModel obj = //method to get required instance of SubscriptionDetailModel
...
obj.cap = obj.cap != null && obj.cap.Any() ? obj.cap : null;
obj.filter = obj.filter != null && obj.filter.Any() ? obj.filter : null;
//call to your serialize method
```

If you are using `Json.NET` then take a look here [about conditional serializing](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

Simply, if you can modify `SubscriptionDetailModel` class, then add methods as following:

```
public bool ShouldSerializecap()
{
    return this.cap != null && this.cap.Any();
}

public bool ShouldSerializefilter()
{
    return this.filter != null && this.filter.Any();
}
```

Comment: Good option indeed if using JSON.NET. If not, setting to null is the only option.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Setting to null or creating own custom serializer. I agree with your answer.

Comment: `public bool ShouldSerializecap()
   {
    return this.cap != null && this.cap.Any();
    }`

by using this on getting filter values cap is removed, but getting values for cap it will return  **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

     `var subscription = new SubscriptionDetailModel();
......      
subscriptionCapDetail.SubscriptionDescription =      item.SubscriptionDescription;
                            subscription.cap.Add(subscriptionCapDetail);`
@MikhailNeofitov

Comment: I did not understand, what the problem now is? As you wrote in comments, you did not use Json.Net, so you should assign null to cap and filter before serializing to json. If it is not suitable for you, I can not suggest you something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Newtonsoft json for serializer then include this on the top of the class which may come empty.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

or else what you can do is which converting the object to JSON you can u use this setting.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
var myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, settings);
```

Comment: As stated in my answer, the list isn't null. That is the reason it isn't excluded.

Comment: u can set the object to null then use this setting's it will omit the empty thing.

Comment: Which is my answer indeed.